# Kendo Template anchor tag

Tags: kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

How do I have the variable value be in an anchor tag  in my grid column server template?

```
.Columns( columns=> 
{
     columns.Bound(c =>c.Text).Template(@<text href='home/index/#=Text#'><a></a></text>);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way of doing this is changing it to use the `ClientTemplate` rather than template like so:

```
.Columns( columns=> 
{
     columns.Bound(c =>c.Text).ClientTemplate("<a href='home/index/#=data.Text#'>#=data.Text#</a>");
})
```

If you have something a bit more advanced then pulling this out into either a function or a `kendoTemplate` will make life a lot easier.